# How can I pass the value of a current row into a subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find all of the divisors of numbers between 1 and 100, I have a table of all int's between 1 and 100.

Using that table I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE divisors AS
SELECT a.n AS num, (select COUNT(b.n) FROM ints as b WHERE num % b.n = 0) FROM ints AS a;
```

But the subquery does not recognize "num" from the outer query.

How can I pass a value like this into a sub query?

Comment: So don't use the alias.

Comment: Indeed use `a.n` in place of `num` inside subquery.

Comment: Don't just say "thanks" to the user who answered your question. Up-vote his answer, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a correlated query.  But, two things to understand:

- Always use qualified column names when your query has multiple tables.
- The correlation clause is not going to recognize column aliases from the `SELECT`.  It only recognizes columns from the outer `FROM`.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE divisors AS
    SELECT i.n AS num,
           (select COUNT(i2.n) FROM ints i2 WHERE i.n % i2.n = 0)
    FROM ints i;
```

You'll also notice that the table aliases are abbreviations for the table name, not arbitrary letters.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the list of divsors:

```
SELECT a.n,b.n
FROM ints a
JOIN ints b
    ON b.n < a.n AND a.n % b.n = 0
ORDER BY a.n
```

To get a count of the number of divisors for each number, try this:

```
SELECT a.n,count(distinct b.n) as `num_divisors`
FROM ints a
JOIN ints b
    ON b.n < a.n AND a.n % b.n = 0
GROUP BY a.n
ORDER BY a.n
```

Comment: How would I then add up all the divisors for each number to get a table with every number from 1 - 100 as the first column and then the number of divisors for that number as the second column? For example: 1|1
#     2|2
#     3|2
#     4|3
#     5|2
#     6|4
#     7|2
#     8|4
#     9|3
#     10|4